# Estimating the number of connected components of a curve contained in a given set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space and $\Omega\subset X$ an open set. Take $x\in\Omega$ and choose $r>0$ such that the open ball $B(x,r)\subset B(x,2r)\subset \Omega$. Let $\gamma:[0,1]\to X$ be a Lipschitz curve.

Is it possible to divide $\gamma$ in a finite number of subcurves $\gamma_i :[a_i,b_i]\to X$, with $0\le a_i\le b_i\le 1$ ($\gamma_i=\gamma_{|[a_i,b_i]}$), such that each curve $\gamma_i$ lies entirely either in $\Omega$ or $X\setminus B(x,r)$?

If we can prove that for some $\lambda\in [1,2)$, the cardinality of the set $\partial B(x,\lambda r)\cap \gamma([0,1])$ is finite then, the result should be true, however I can't formalize it.

If I assume on the contrary that for every $\lambda \in [1,2)$ such inersection is enumarable, then it seem to imply that the length of $\gamma$ is infinite, which is an absurd. Does this makes any sense?

Comment: $a_1 \leq b_i$? by divide you mean $a_0 = 0,\ a_{i+1} = b_i,\ b_n = 1$? what's $\gamma([1,2])$?

Comment: @user2345215, there is no ordering in the i's, however, in the end we must have that $\gamma$ is the union of the $\gamma_i$'s. I have fixed the typo that you poointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't even need the Lipschitz continuity, the uniform continuity you get from the compactness of the parameter interval suffices for the partition.

Let $C = \gamma^{-1}(\overline{B(x,r)})$ and $D = \gamma^{-1}(X\setminus B(x,2r))$. Call $s,t \in C$ (without loss of generality $s \leqslant t$) equivalent if $[s,t]\cap D = \varnothing$, and similarly for $D$. By the uniform continuity, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $s\in C, t\in D \Rightarrow \lvert s-t\rvert \geqslant \delta$, and hence we have $\operatorname{dist}(E_1,E_2) \geqslant 2\delta$ if $E_1,E_2$ are two distinct equivalence classes of either $C$ or $D$. Therefore, there are only finitely many equivalence classes in each, $C$ and $D$.

For such an equivalence class $E$, let $I(E) = [\inf E,\sup E]$. That gives you finitely many disjoint subintervals $[\alpha_i,\beta_i]$, $1 \leqslant i \leqslant m$ with $\alpha_i \leqslant \beta_i < \alpha_{i+1}$, and $\alpha_i \in C \iff \beta_i \in C \iff \alpha_{i+1} \in D$. Let $t_0 = 0$, $t_n = 1$, and for $1 \leqslant i < n$, let $t_i = \frac{1}{2}(\beta_i + \alpha_{i+1})$.

Then for $1 \leqslant i < n$ we have $\gamma(t_i) \in B(x,2r)\setminus \overline{B(x,r)}$, and for all $i < n$ either $\gamma([t_i,t_{i+1}]) \subset B(x,2r)$ or $\gamma([t_i,t_{i+1}]) \subset X\setminus \overline{B(x,r)}$.

Comment: I can't find any error in the argument, however, the Peano curve don't leave my mind. Your proof just show that it would work even in the case where we have a Peano curve. Am I right?

Comment: Right. Even that needs time to go from one corner of the square to another.

Comment: Well, that's a great answer. Thank you again @DanielFischer.

Comment: Dear @Daniel. I was discussing this problem with a friend and there is a point which is not clear to us. The point is that for $s\in C$ or $D$, $\gamma^{-1}\{s\}$ can be, for example, a infinite set and hence your argument with the equivalence classes seems to not condider all the possibilities. If the curve is injective or if $[0,1]\setminus (C\cup D)$ has only a finite number of connected componentes then, it seems that the argument is true, however, in the more general case, like a Peano curve, it seems that it cannot be true.

Comment: $C$ and $D$ are disjoint compact sets. Thus they have a positive distance $\delta := \min \{\lvert s-t\rvert : s\in C,t\in D\} > 0$. That means there are only finitely many components of $G = [0,1]\setminus (C\cup D)$ with one endpoint in $C$ and the other in $D$, since such a component must have length $\geqslant\delta$. $G$ can have infinitely many components with both endpoints in $C$ or both in $D$, but that's no problem because we partition only in the components of $G$ connecting $C$ and $D$. Informally, we can regard the components with both endpoints in $C$ as belonging to $C$.